# Question about java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: quickfix/MessageStoreFactory

Tags: java, quickfixj

I have a problem when I run my Java application for a FIX application. I have added all the QuickFIX/J jars to build the FIX application. But when I run my jar I always get this error:

```
Application: TestMarketdataRequest 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: quickfix/MessageStoreFactory
    at com.dxtr.fastmatch.FastmatchMDRequest.<init>(FastmatchMDRequest.java:14)
    at com.dxtr.fastmatch.FastmatchMDRequest.main(FastmatchMDRequest.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: quickfix.MessageStoreFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 2 more
```

My question: How do I fix this and why do I get this error when I did add QuickFIX/J in my depedencies?

Answer (score 1):

Include the dependency jar in your classpath when you run the main class using the `-cp` option:

```
java -cp quickfixj.jar MainClass
```

> **-classpath classpath**
>   **-cp classpath**
>   Specifies a list of directories, JAR files, and ZIP archives to search for class files. Separate class path entries with semicolons (;). Specifying -classpath or -cp overrides any setting of the CLASSPATH environment variable.

More on the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).

Comment: ok my application run but when i want to readfile using example banzai readfile my code cannot read my config

Comment: this is my read input stream InputStream inputStream = null;
             if (args.length == 0) {
                 inputStream = TestMarketdataRequest.class.getResourceAsStream("initiator.config");
             } else if (args.length == 1) {
                 inputStream = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
             }
             if (inputStream == null) {
                 System.out.println("usage: " + TestMarketdataRequest.class.getName() + " [configFile].");
                 return;
             }

Comment: and this is what i got frommy code usage: com.dxtr.fastmatch.marketdatarequestapps.TestMarketdataRequest [configFile]. so i think i cannot read my file here

Comment: Oh, I thought you had a different problem. Could you please update your question to include this information, too? It's a bit hard to tell from the comment how the code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

this is closed. i have add executable jar in my pom. so it is closed right now thanks all